# Variable in AWK

Tags: ubuntu, shell-scripting, awk

How can I add a variable within awk command? below is my command:

```
cat /home/ubuntu/test/copy.txt | awk 'NR==21{print ".host = "$line";"}1'
```

$line is basically an IP address which is retrieved from a text file. With the above command the output looks like

```
.host = ;
```

Any immediate help would be really appreciated.

**Format of copy.txt**

```
backend default {
#.host = value; need to be here
.port = "8080";
}
```

Comment: do you want to get `line` variable from file or from other source?

Comment: And what is the exact format of the `copy.txt` file?

Comment: @RomeoNinov- please check my update. also, regarding line, I am already capturing it from a file using while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in `awk` can be transferred from shell on this way:

```
awk -v variable=$line '.....
```

and used inside on this way:

```
awk -v line1=$line 'NR==21 {print ".host = "line1";"}1'
```

The variable should be set beforehand in bash so the things become:

```
line=192.168.0.10
awk -v line1=$line 'NR==21 {print ".host = "line1";"}1' /path/to/file ...
```

Also you do not need `cat`, just use this way:

```
awk '....' /home/ubuntu/test/copy.txt
```

To store the output in a file you should use something like:

```
awk '....' /home/ubuntu/test/copy.txt >/home/ubuntu/test/new_copy.txt
```

and the result will be stored in `/home/ubuntu/test/new_copy.txt`

Comment: It works, however the file doesnt seem to be saved. The reason is I am able to see the file with the update printed, but checking the file in another window, there's no content in line 21. Any idea why?

Comment: Because `awk` only print the content. Let me add more explanations to the answer

Comment: Thanks, it works, but in line1 should be updated with the value along with "" (double quotes)
example: "192.168.0.10". Now it is coming as 192.168.10.0. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @serverstackqns, before exec the `awk` you should run command like `line=192.168.0.10` and in `awk` variable `line1` will get this value

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please update the answer with this too.

Comment: @serverstackqns, done. Maybe you should spend some time to learn `bash` scripting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140551/discussion-between-serverstackqns-and-romeo-ninov).